# send picture from android to wcf

Tags: android, image, wcf, upload

i need send picture from android to service WCF.

My android function:

```
public void uploadPicture() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{


    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URL_UPLOAD_PICTURE+"image24.png");

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    File myfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documentation/wallpaper-3.jpg"); 

    try{
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(myfile, "image/png"));
    httppost.setEntity(entity);

    String responseString = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);


    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and my operation contract in service WCF

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "/UploadImage/{filename}")]
    void UploadImage(string filename, System.IO.Stream image);
```

and my function in WCF

```
public void UploadImage(string filename, System.IO.Stream image)
    {
        FileStream fileToUpload = new FileStream("C:\\FileUpload\\" + filename, FileMode.Create);
        byte[] bytearray = new byte[1000000];

        int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = image.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);

            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        } while (bytesRead > 0);


        fileToUpload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
        fileToUpload.Close();
        fileToUpload.Dispose();
    }
```

I think is really easy, but when i see image saved, windows say me image is incorrect.

any idea?

Comment: Can you define "windows say me image is incorrect"?

Comment: open the image file in something like wordpad.

Comment: Windows show: photo display windows can not open this picture because the file appears to be corrupted or too large

Comment: If i open image file with notepad++, show meaningless text. 
©©=Ë¯sšépŽÎÝ†Ø’JQw«ÉË†¶–úA2úeYàðOØsŸCQJùÒú¦±üýr5Å6s¿´FU4wÔ¡â< Õ¨Ç2,ç¡b§Ö’
M4Õj–Ð6aÛw‰Kòiág=
‡=5
+¯Uüåÿ

Comment: Nice, now i have solution. Only need remove header in image and window recognize as picture.

thanks

Comment: @user1722874 Did you get your code working? Please reply because I am also trying to send an image from android to .NET.

Comment: Don't you have a data contract?